# Could it be problematic to point to a character array in a member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2010, memory, c++98

```
int setString(char *pcString)
{
    if( NULL == pcString )
    {
        pcString = "";
    }
        
    if( NULL == m_pcData )
    {
        m_pcData = new char[m_nBufferLength];
        memset(m_pcData, '\0', m_nBufferLength);
    }


    int nCurrentBuffer      = 0;
    int nLength             = 0;
    int nInputStringLength  = 0;

    nLength             = strlen(m_pcData) + knNULL_CHARACTER_SPACE;
    nCurrentBuffer      = (m_nBufferLength > nLength) ? m_nBufferLength : nLength ;
    nInputStringLength  = strlen(pcString) + knNULL_CHARACTER_SPACE;

    if( nCurrentBuffer < nInputStringLength )
    {
        delete[] m_pcData;
        m_pcData = new char[nInputStringLength];
    }

    strcpy(m_pcData, pcString);

    return nInputStringLength;
}
```

line5 `pcString = ""` -> Could this be a problem, depending on how the code is written later?

It was pointed out that it could be a problem in the lecture.

he said

```
pcString = new char;
pcString[0] = '\0';
```

is better code.

But I cannot understand why?
Can someone give me some explains?

```
pcString = "";
strcpy(pcString, "C++ Problem");
```

Is this one of those cases?

Comment: You can't copy 12 characters into 1 matter which way you allocate it. But ys, trying to `strcpy` into a string literal is undefined behavior. Why not use `std::string` ?

Comment: Did you compile this function? You should have gotten a warning on the line `pcString = "";`. I don't agree with your professor's workaround to this warning, but the existence of a warning is a problem. (For what it's worth: I would address the warning by declaring the parameter to be `const char *pcString`.)

Comment: `pcString = "";` is not legal `C++`. Unfortunately compilers are too tolerant of that error. Your professor's workaround is bad because `pcString` won't be *null terminated* and will cause undefined behavior when you use standard functions like `std::strlen`.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `pcString[0] = '\0';`?

Comment: @UnderSnow The function declaration compared with its definition does not make sense. The parameter shall have the qualifier const. Also the function definition looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pcString is declared as pointer to character(s), so it is implicitly assumed that these characters can be changed. The literal "" is a string of constants characters, so it can not be changed. For backward compatibility reasons, C++ allows you to make the assignment:

```
pcString = "";
```

but the following code will not compiled:

```
const char* str0 = "";
pcString = str0;
```

So, you can add `const` before `char* pcString` and the function will be ok:

```
int setString(const char *pcString)
{
  //....
}
```

If the pcString string should remain changeable, then the assignment:

```
pcString = "";
```

can be a problem with the following code:

```
*pcString = '\0'; // undefined behavior (1)
```

or

```
delete[] pcString; // undefined behavior (2)
```

(1) - the try to modifier constant string
(2) - the try to release unallocated memory

Note. If you make the correction:

```
pcString = new char;
pcString[0] = '\0';
```

then you need to provide for the release of the allocated memory.